# Why is the spread operator returning an empty array from a promise in useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a simple game I've made which saves hiscores (using Google Firebase). I have a function (getHiscores()) that returns a promise, gets the hiscores from the database, and then resolves or rejects with the outcome of the database query as the parameter.

I'm using React for my front-end, and have a hiscores component that uses getHiscores() on mount, .then() uses the result to determine what to display. However, for a reason that I can't work out, I can't use the spread operator with the result returned by the promise (i.e. setHiscores([...result]), although I can use it without (i.e. setHiscores(result))? This is problematic because without the spread operator, react doesn't register a change and so the result is not displayed and the array is supposedly empty.

The only solution I've come up with so far is using useEffect() with no dependency array to keep trying to display the hiscores until it succeeds, this does work but leads to React warning that the maximum depth limit has been reached and just seems a bit precarious.

Please see the code below with relevant comments

```
function HiscoresDisplay(props) {
  let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  let [error, setError] = useState(false);
  let [hiscores, setHiscores] = useState([]);
  let [hiscoresTable, setHiscoresTable] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getHiscores(props.levelToShow.getLevelName())
      .then((result) => {
        setHiscores(result);  // Note: this is where I want to use setHiscores([...result]), but it never works because [...result] seems to always return as length: 0 with no items
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setError(true);
        setLoading(false);  
      })
  }, [])
  
  // This is the solution so far, but it would be far better if I could use the spread operator on the array and then have a useEffect() with hiscores as the dependency - as it stands right now, this does not work because React cannot tell that hiscores[] has changed due to the lack of ...spread operator!
  useEffect(() => {
    if((hiscoresTable === null || hiscoresTable.length === 0) && !error) {
      let newHiscoresTable = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < hiscores.length; i++) {
        newHiscoresTable.push(
          <tr>
            <td>{i + 1}</td>
            <td>{hiscores[i].name}</td>
            <td>{new Date(hiscores[i].time * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      }
      setHiscoresTable([...newHiscoresTable]);
    } 
  })
  
  return(
    <>
      <header>
        <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center', width: '100%'}}>Where's Wally?</h1>
      </header>
      <p className="under-header">{props.levelToShow.getLevelName()} Hiscores</p>
      <button onClick={() => props.setDisplay(0)} style={{display: 'block', margin: '0 auto'}}>◀&nbsp; Back to Main Menu</button>

      {loading 
      ? <h1 className="loading-levels">Loading hiscores...</h1> 
      : null }

      {error
      ? <h1 className="loading-levels">Failed to load hiscores</h1>
      : null }

      {!error && !loading
      ? <div className="hiscores-container">
          <table className="hiscores" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${props.levelToShow.getImgSrc()})`}}>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Time</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {hiscoresTable}
            </tbody>          
          </table>  
        </div>
        : null}
    </>
  )
}
```

I hope that makes sense, I've spent so long trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong but I just can't get my head around it!

Any further details needed please ask

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us how the data looks like? With a console.log and why do you want to spread it in the first place?

Comment: Sounds like `getHiscores` might be mutating the result after the promise resolves. Without seeing that code, it's impossible to verify but the symptoms line up.